# Why isn't the work done by gas equal to the heat income in an isobaric process?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why isn't the work done by gas equal in quantity to the heat income in an isobaric process where for example an frictionless cilinder is closed by an frictionless piston? Don't we have the same energy used by the gas to expand the voume that we got from the heat coming in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't we have the same energy used by the gas to expand the volume that
> we got from the heat coming in?

No, because part of the heat added during the process increases the temperature of the gas and thus increases the internal energy of the gas. From the first law

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$
$$W=Q-\Delta U$$

The isobaric expansion work is

$$W=P(V_{2}-V_1)$$

Consider an ideal gas. From the ideal gas law, one mole, isobaric process

$$\frac {V_2}{T_2}=\frac {V_1}{T_1}$$

For expansion, $V_{2}>V_1$ and therefore $T_{2}>T_1$ for an increase in temperature.

for any process, ideal gas,

$$\Delta U=C_{v}(T_{2}-T_1)$$

Plugging into the second equation

$$W=Q-C_{v}(T_{2}-T_1)$$

So only for an isothermal process, where $\Delta T=0$, will the expansion work done equal the heat added.

Hope this helps.